# Dapper mapping columns to entity properties?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper's Query<> to search for a number of records:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public string Name {get; set}
    public int CategoryId {get; set}
]

public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int categoryId)
{
    var connection = DataContext.Database.Connection;

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = @categoryId";

    var result = connection.Query<Product>(sql, new { categoryId });

    return result;
}
```

The query itself returns the requested records but each object in the list has empty fields.

So how can I map the columns to the entity's properties?

I would not like to add column aliases in the sql statement. Decorating the entity's properties is also not an option because the entities are generated by the EF designer.

Comment: You can use the [DapperExtensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) package and create a custom mapper for your class by inheriting from ClassMapper<Product> or AutoMapper<Product>. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183310/can-i-specify-db-column-names-for-dapper-dot-net-mappings) for more info. Don't have time to give a full answer. I believe you will also need to change from using the Query method to using the Get method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well your Product class must be defined such as to match the result coming back from the query. So what you can do is -

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int categoryId)
{
    var connection = DataContext.Database.Connection;

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = @categoryId";

    var result = connection.Query<Product>(sql, new { categoryId }).Select(p => new Product {
           Id = (int)p.ProductId,
           Name = (string)p.ProductName,
           CategoryId  = (int)p.ProductCategoryId
        });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer because for one-off queries and mapping, this solution will suffice. However, for many queries that need to be mapping, DapperExtensions is the way to go.

Comment: Yes for many queries or some complex objects you need to use DapperExtensions. Anyways, Glad to help you and thanks if you can upvote my answer.. :)