# Dapper. Map to SQL Column with spaces in column names

Tags: c#, dapper

I've managed to get something up and running today as small sandbox/POC project, but have seemed to bump my head on one issue...

**Question:**

> Is there a way to get dapper to map to SQL column names with spaces in them.

I have something to this effect as my result set.

**For example:**

```
SELECT 001 AS [Col 1], 
       901 AS [Col 2],
       00454345345345435349 AS [Col 3],
       03453453453454353458 AS [Col 4] 
FROM [Some Schema].[Some Table]
```

And my class would look like this

```
    public class ClassA
    {          
        public string Col1 { get; set; }    

        public string Col2 { get; set; }

        ///... etc
     }
```

My implementation looks like this at the moment

```
 public Tuple<IList<TClass>, IList<TClass2>> QueryMultiple<TClass, TClass2>(object parameters)
 {
      List<TClass> output1;
      List<TClass2> output2;

      using (var data = this.Connection.QueryMultiple(this.GlobalParameter.RpcProcedureName, parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
      {
           output1 = data.Read<TClass>().ToList();
           output2 = data.Read<TClass2>().ToList();
      }

      var result = new Tuple<IList<TClass>, IList<TClass2>>(output1, output2);
      return result;
  }
```

**Note: The SQL cant be modified in any way.**

Currently I'm going through the dapper code, and my only foreseeable solution is to add some code to "persuade" the column comparison, but not having much luck so far.

I've seen on StackOverflow that there are things like dapper extensions, but I'm hoping I can get this done without adding an extention, if not. I'll take whatever is quickest to implement.

Comment: I have this same need. I got around it by adding aliases to all the columns in my query but that's incredibly tedious. The solutions below may work but it would be really nice if Dapper could just add a property/parameter to ignore spaces instead of everyone having to add customer mappers. These are legal names and it should be able to map them with little effort.

Comment: This is the best solution I found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856158/5504438

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option here would be to go via the dynamic / non-generic API, and then fetch the values out via the `IDictionary<string,object>` API per row, but that might be a bit tedious.

As an alternative, you can create a custom mapper, and tell dapper about it; for example:

```
SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(ClassA), new RemoveSpacesMap());
```

with:

```
class RemoveSpacesMap : Dapper.SqlMapper.ITypeMap
{

    System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo SqlMapper.ITypeMap.FindConstructor(string[] names, Type[] types)
    {
        return null;
    }

    SqlMapper.IMemberMap SqlMapper.ITypeMap.GetConstructorParameter(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, string columnName)
    {
        return null;
    }

    SqlMapper.IMemberMap SqlMapper.ITypeMap.GetMember(string columnName)
    {
        var prop = typeof(ClassA).GetProperty(columnName.Replace(" ", ""));
        return prop == null ? null : new PropertyMemberMap(columnName, prop);
    }
    class PropertyMemberMap : Dapper.SqlMapper.IMemberMap
    {
        private string columnName;
        private PropertyInfo property;
        public PropertyMemberMap(string columnName, PropertyInfo property)
        {
            this.columnName = columnName;
            this.property = property;
        }
        string SqlMapper.IMemberMap.ColumnName
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        System.Reflection.FieldInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Field
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        Type SqlMapper.IMemberMap.MemberType
        {
            get { return property.PropertyType; }
        }

        System.Reflection.ParameterInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Parameter
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Property
        {
            get { return property; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to remove dapper for the time being, as it was needed for a small (rushed) proof of concept. But I do like the framework/library, I definitely think i'll be adding it back in.

Comment: Ah .. looking at this I suppose I would have needed to implement the FindConstructor method in `RemoveSpacesMap`, right? Oops! Sorry.

Comment: Copying your default implementation did the trick: `return typeof(ClassA).GetConstructor(new Type[0])`.. should have poked around a bit more before posting; sorry.

Comment: I'm trying this solution.  It's asking me to implement `FindExplicitConstructor()`.     Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

There's a nuget package **Dapper.FluentMap** that allows you to add column name mappings (including spaces). It's similar to EntityFramework.

```
// Entity class.
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Mapper class.
public class CustomerMapper : EntityMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMapper()
    {
        Map(p => p.Name).ToColumn("Customer Name");
    }
}

// Initialise like so - 
FluentMapper.Initialize(a => a.AddMap(new CustomerMapper()));
```

see https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap for more.

Comment: @David, I initialized the FluentMapper. But it does not seem to work. I guess I am missing something. Could you elaborate how can I make it to work, if my current code is  `return connection.Query<Customer>("SELECT 'My Name' [Customer Name]").First();`, How this can be made to work to return Customer object?

Comment: @user007 can you show me your Customer class? And where are you doing the mapping?

Comment: @DavidMcEleney, I used exactly the same Customer class you had. Could you elaborate where and how you wrote `FluentMapper.Initialize(a => a.AddMap(new CustomerMapper()));` I created a new class as below: `public class DapperFluentMapInitializer
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
            FluentMapper.Initialize(a => a.AddMap(new CustomerMapper()));
        }
    }`

Comment: @user007 It's about 5 months ago, so my memory's a little rusty - what kind of app are you writing? E.g. if it's a web app, open Global.asax & add it to the Application_Start event....

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when trying to get mapped results from a call to the system sp_spaceused procedure.  Marc's code didn't quite work for me as it complained about not being able to find a default constructor.  I also made my version generic so it could theoretically be re-used.  This may not be the fastest performing piece of code, but it works for me and in our situation these calls are made infrequently.

```
class TitleCaseMap<T> : SqlMapper.ITypeMap where T: new()
{
    ConstructorInfo SqlMapper.ITypeMap.FindConstructor(string[] names, Type[] types)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    }

    SqlMapper.IMemberMap SqlMapper.ITypeMap.GetConstructorParameter(ConstructorInfo constructor, string columnName)
    {
        return null;
    }

    SqlMapper.IMemberMap SqlMapper.ITypeMap.GetMember(string columnName)
    {
        string reformattedColumnName = string.Empty;

        foreach (string word in columnName.Replace("_", " ").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            reformattedColumnName += char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1).ToLower();
        }

        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(reformattedColumnName);

        return prop == null ? null : new PropertyMemberMap(prop);
    }

    class PropertyMemberMap : SqlMapper.IMemberMap
    {
        private readonly PropertyInfo _property;

        public PropertyMemberMap(PropertyInfo property)
        {
            _property = property;
        }
        string SqlMapper.IMemberMap.ColumnName
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        FieldInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Field
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        Type SqlMapper.IMemberMap.MemberType
        {
            get { return _property.PropertyType; }
        }

        ParameterInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Parameter
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        PropertyInfo SqlMapper.IMemberMap.Property
        {
            get { return _property; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question nevertheless i faced the same problem in my last project, so i just created an own mapper using attributes.

I defined an attribute class called ColumnNameAttribute.cs

```
using System;

namespace DapperHelper.Attributes
{
    [System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    sealed class ColumNameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private string _columName;

        public string ColumnName
        {
            get { return _columName; }
            set { _columName = value; }
        }

        public ColumNameAttribute(string columnName)
        {
            _columName = columnName;
        }
    }
}
```

After defining the attribute, i implemeted a dynamic mapper that uses the `Query` method from Dapper but works as the `Query<T>`:

```
using Dapper;
using DapperHelper.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DapperHelper.Tools
{
    public class DynamicMapper<T> :IDisposable where  T : class, new()
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _propertiesMap;

        public DynamicMapper()
        {
            _propertiesMap = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ColumNameAttribute)) is ColumNameAttribute columNameAttribute)
                {
                    _propertiesMap.Add(columNameAttribute.ColumnName, propertyInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    _propertiesMap.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<T> QueryDynamic(IDbConnection dbConnection, string sqlQuery)
        {
            List<dynamic> results = dbConnection.Query(sqlQuery).ToList();

            List<T> output = new List<T>();

            foreach (dynamic dynObj in results)
            {
                output.Add(AssignPropertyValues(dynObj));
            }

            return output;
        }

        private T AssignPropertyValues(dynamic dynamicObject)
        {
            T output = new T();

            RouteValueDictionary dynamicObjProps = new RouteValueDictionary(dynamicObject);

            foreach (var propName in dynamicObjProps.Keys)
            {
                if (_propertiesMap.TryGetValue(propName, out PropertyInfo propertyMapped)
                    && dynamicObjProps.TryGetValue(propName, out object value))
                {
                    propertyMapped.SetValue(output, value);
                }
            }

            return output;
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _propertiesMap.Clear(); 
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you have to refer to your Model class and define the attribute:

```
 using DapperHelper.Attributes;

namespace Testing
    {
        public class Sample
        {
            public int SomeColumnData { get; set; }

            [ColumnName("Your Column Name")]
            public string SpecialColumn{ get; set; }

        }
    }
```

and then you can implement something like this:

```
DynamicMapper<Sample> mapper = new DynamicMapper<Sample>();

List<Sample> samples = mapper.QueryDynamic(connection, "SELECT * FROM Samples");
```

I hope it can help someone looking for an alternative.

Comment: Very nice answer! I wish you posted this 9 years ago  But this seems like a flexible solution. Upvoted for sure :)

Comment: @RohanBüchner thanks mate, i successfully implemented it in a project recently, it saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class (e.g, Employee)

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a Mapper class to Map the columns which are retrieved from DB (like SQL).

For example, if you are retrieving a List of Employees in .Net core (Blazor), your code might look something like below:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeeData()
{
    return await _db.QueryFromSPAsync<Employee, dynamic>("NameOfYourStoredProcedure",new { });
}

// Employee Mapper class

public class EmployeeMapper : EntityMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMapper()
    {
        Map(p => p.ID).ToColumn("ID");
        Map(p => p.FirstName).ToColumn("First Name");
        Map(p => p.LastName).ToColumn("Last Name");
    }
}
```

You can initialise the Mapper as below:

```cs
//In your Program.cs

FluentMapper.Initialize(Map =>
    {
        Map.AddMap(new SLAInsuredMapper());
    }
);
```

**Note: Don't forget to install `Dapper.FluentMap` NuGet package.**