# Read multiple result sets using query multiple

Tags: c#, dapper, multiple-resultsets

My procedure is returning two result sets/tables,
I want to read those two result sets into two different lists and bind that list.

I'm able to read one result set into a list but I tried various ways to read multiple result sets into the dynamic list but it is giving me "TTC Error Oracle".

How to read multiple result sets using QueryMultiple?

Code for reading single result set into dynamic list:

```
public ResponseModel GetDoctorDetails(CustomerRequest data)
{
    try
    {
        var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
        p.Add("p_parameter1", data.PARAMETER1, dbType: OracleDbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, size: 8);
        p.Add("p_parameter2", data.PARAMETER2, dbType: OracleDbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, size: 8);
        p.Add("p_out_cursor", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 0);
        using (var multi = _oracleConnection.QueryMultiple("procedure_name", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            List<dynamic> list = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();

            return new ResponseModel { ResultSet = list, StatusCode = 1, StatusDescription = "Success" };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I tried following ways to read multiple result sets but it is giving me "TTC Error"

```
List<DataTable> list = new List<DataTable>();
list = multi.Read<DataTable>().AsList();
```

and

```
List<List<dynamic>> list = new List<List<dynamic>>();
list = multi.Read<List<dynamic>>().AsList();
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to do `multi.Read` twice. https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple

Comment: They're reading using model, I want to read those result sets dynamically in a list because my result set contains column like "Doctor ID"  and I can't bind "Doctor ID" into my model directly because the column name contains space so I want to read it in a dynamic list.

Comment: You can not avoid space in the column name? Did you try doing `multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();` twice? How will you access property with space in dynamic object?

Comment: I don't have permission to do changes in database so I can't avoid it. and I tried `multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();` twice it is giving an error in first `multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();`. and I can loop through dynamic list using IDictionary and read column value into variable like this `row["Doctor ID"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to do 2 things.

First, you need a way to map with the spaces coming back.  For that, you have to create your own mapper for Dapper to read in.  You can see how to do that here:

[Dapper. Map to SQL Column with spaces in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814972/dapper-map-to-sql-column-with-spaces-in-column-names)

As for multiple queries, you need to just call Read multiple times for each set:

```
 using (var multi = _oracleConnection.QueryMultiple("procedure_name", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            List<dynamic> list1 = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();
            List<dynamic> list2 = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();
            List<dynamic> list3 = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();

            ...
        }
```

Comment: It worked, but now it is giving me "TTC Error" while binding the result sets to lists, if both result sets contains data.

Comment: I think you need to enable multiple active result sets in the connection string.

Comment: How to do it in oracle connection string using .net core?

Comment: Because I tried setting `"CAD": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.50)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEVDB)));User Id=CADILA;Password=CADILA123;Connection Lifetime=60000;Max Pool Size=50;Min Pool Size=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",` but it is giving me an error `'MultipleActiveResultSets' is an invalid connection string attribute`

Comment: if you are using oracle, you have to take a different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772781/using-dapper-querymultiple-in-oracle