# Got NotSupportedException when using Dapper to call a PostgreSQL function with a geography argument

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql, nettopologysuite

I was using Dapper (using `npgsql` data provider with `NetTopologySuite` plugin) to call a PostgreSQL function with a `geography` argument then received a `NotSupportedException`:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The member _location of type NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point cannot be used as a parameter value
at Dapper.SqlMapper.LookupDbType(Type type, String name, Boolean demand, ITypeHandler& handler) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 417
at Dapper.SqlMapper.CreateParamInfoGenerator(Identity identity, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean removeUnused, IList`1 literals) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 2516
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetCacheInfo(Identity identity, Object exampleParameters, Boolean addToCache) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1707
at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteScalarImplAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 1207
...
```

But it works fine when I use `NpgsqlCommand` with type specified via `AddWithValue` method.

How can I make Dapper map `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point` to `geography`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some search I found an [unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483668/3801371) that solved my problem.

Make sure I added [Npgsql.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.NetTopologySuite) package and its mapper is enabled `connection.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite();` then the ADO.Net command works fine.

I added a custom `Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeHandler`:

```
public class GeographyTypeMapper : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Geometry> {
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, Geometry value) {
        if (parameter is NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter) {
            npgsqlParameter.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Geography;
            npgsqlParameter.NpgsqlValue = value;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public override Geometry Parse(object value) {
        if (value is Geometry geometry) {
            return geometry;
        } 

        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Then use it `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new GeographyTypeMapper());` and everything works fine.

Comment: Another example:
https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620

Answer (score 0):

I'd you just upgraded to Npgsql 4, you will need to uses one of the spatial plugins. Read [the release notes] (http://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/4.0.html#improved-spatial-support-postgis).

Comment: I managed to map `Point` to `geography` using `NetToologySuite` plugin but Dapper didn't understand the mapping. I also edited my question to make it clearer.