# what's the best way to translate a data set to a CLR type

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

Working on a legacy application where Data Access repository always returns a data set. Changing to any ORM frameworks is not an option for me at this point, looking for best options to map result set to a CLR type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of 2 easy ways to do this.

1 - Use [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

```
const string query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
return connection.Query<User>(query);
```

With Dapper you don't even have to worry about getting the DataTable, just query the SqlConnection and get your type back.

2 - Use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/):

```
List<User> users = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<User>>(
sourceDataTable.CreateDataReader());
```

Automapper can map your DataTable to your type.

Both methods require your class to have property names that match the column names in your source data.

I think they are both available as NuGet packages

Comment: Thank you Glen. Type's property names do not match with Database column names, apparently, automapper has create mapper to define mappings. I will explore the options suggested and will update this thread

Comment: Yes automapper allows you to define the mappings. Apparently this can also be achieved with Dapper. See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615036/5152001). Given the choice I would probably go with Dapper as it is specially designed for this purpose and will almost certainly require less code. I'm not sure how well automapper caters for DataTable mappings.