# Reading subset of the table using Dapper in C#

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using Dapper in the project, and it's ok if I need to get either the single primitive type (int, decimal, string, etc) or any db entity, but I need to read just 2 columns from the table, and I faced with lots of the challenges here:

This is a simple query:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1
```

Where I expect to receive string and int

And this is how I read the data once the query is implemented:

```
var field1 =  (await result.ReadAsync<string, int>()).FirstOrDefault();
```

And this is not compilable.
I tried to create the class which contains 2 fields: string and int and use that type instead of  .
So it results to the following correction:

```
var field1 =  (await result.ReadAsync<MyData>()).FirstOrDefault();

class MyData
{
string...

int ...
}
```

and it compiles but I get null for string and the proper data for int.

The query itself is correct, I tested it and it's fine.
So the question is how to read the 2 columns?

Comment: I think for your original code what you wanted was `ReadAsync<Tuple<string, int>>()`

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach looks correct. Dapper by default maps on convention. Name of properties in your `MyData` class and the name of column should be same so that Dapper can map correctly.

So, your `MyData` class should look something like this:

```
class MyData
{
    string col1...
    int col2...
}
```

In case, your property names have to be different, you need to modify your query to use column alias something like below:

```
SELECT col1 AS MyProperty1, col2 AS MyProperty2 FROM Table1
```

Also note that in case of complex query/mapping, your table name should match with your name of POCO/Entity class.

There are ways to override the default mapping. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902674/5779732) question for detailed discussion on Dapper's mapping.