# Load an object from SQL Server but use different object properties for the c# class

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm not sure if I'm being clear in the title but I'd like to "load" information from a SQL Server database into a list of objects. I'm new to c# and honestly haven't done any coding in a while.

Essentially the table would have columns: app_name, app_type, app_disposition and the object has properties: name, type, disposition. I've got what I want working using Dapper and simply making the object properties the same as the table columns.

Just curious if you could load but using different object property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Dapper, simplest solution is to use aliases.

Your class is:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //Declare other properties here
}
```

And, you fill this class as below:

```
string sql = "SELECT app_name as Name, [include other columns here]
              FROM MyTable";

using (var conn = GetOpenConnection())
{
    var myPocoList = conn.Query<MyPoco>(sql);
}
```

`GetOpenConnection` method above simply returns open connection depending on your RDBMS.

Please note that there are many other ways to map the miss-matching column and property names. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902674/5779732) Q&A for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, and you have to use the "Custom Mapping" feature. Here's a detailed article I wrote on the subject, along with code samples, to shows how you can do it.

https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-columns-mapping-1cd45dfd51d6

Hint: Use Dapper.Fluent-Map plugin