# c# dapper stored procedure returning null

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, dapper

Everything I try to do it just keeps spiting out null.
This is the method that gets the data

```
public List<Item> getItems(string item_name)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("dbConn")))
    {
        connection.Open();

        return connection.Query<Item>($"SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE itm_name = 'Jaje'").ToList();
    }
}
```

NOTE: **The query is hardcoded for testing purposes, usually replaced by a stored procedure**
Even while hardcoded it still returns null.

The item class

```
public class Item
{ 
    public int _itm_id { get; set; }
    public string _itm_name { get; set; }
    public float _itm_price { get; set; }

}
```

I also have the following code in the .xaml.cs file that runs on a button press

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items = da.getItems(txtboxItemNameSearch.Text.Trim());
```

It always returns _itm_id = 0, _itm_name = null, _itm_price = 0.
The connection is open, the insert method works fine. The row is not empty. I copied the select hardcoded statement from a query that worked perfectly.

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`itm_id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itm_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`itm_price` FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`itm_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `itm_name` (`itm_name`)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database column is named `itm_id`, but your C# class property name is `_itm_id`. The names need to match for Dapper to assign values from the `MySqlDataReader` row to the C# object.

Change your class to the following and the mapping should succeed:

```
public class Item
{ 
    public int itm_id { get; set; }
    public string itm_name { get; set; }
    public float itm_price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I wanted to try that since it makes perfect sense. But I went to bed. The problem with that is that my variables in the stored procedure are named _itm_name and _itm_price. And in the insert method https://pastebin.com/iPxCXJ17 I have to use those sql variables to equal them with the user input. Will I have to rename all my variables to something like just itm_name ?

Comment: Update: I've adjusted everything. Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default handling for the mapper built into Dapper requires that class property names match the column names or be separated by an underscore.

For example, the column `ItemName` will match the property `ItemName` or `Item_Name` and vice versa. There's more complex mapping available for columns that don't follow this scheme, if you want to go that route see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536863/3516555).

I created a quick example.

SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
GO

USE TEST;
GO

CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Price] MONEY
    );
GO

INSERT INTO ITEM ([Name], [Price]) 
SELECT 'item 1', 10
UNION SELECT 'item 2', 20
UNION SELECT 'item 3', 30
UNION SELECT 'item 4', 40
UNION SELECT 'item 5', 50
UNION SELECT 'item 6', 60
UNION SELECT 'item 7', 70
UNION SELECT 'item 8', 80
UNION SELECT 'item 9', 90
UNION SELECT 'item 10', 100;
GO
```

C#

```
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = getItems("Item 1");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", item.id);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", item.name);
                Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", item.price);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static IList<Item> getItems(string name)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"))
            {    
                return connection.Query<Item>($"SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE name = @name",
                    new { name }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]