# Dapper query result sets Pk of table as null in objects

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql database using dapper but the result sets id (primary key) and foreign key as nulls. Other attributes have values.

I tried to change sql query from select * from courses to full form as select id,name,did from courses.

```
    Course{
        public Course()
        {

        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public bool Is_Elective { get; set; }
        public string DId { get; set; }
        public int Sem { get; set; }

    }

   class CourseDAO
    {
        private readonly MySqlConnection conn;
        private string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=university;Uid=root;Pwd=*****;";

        public CourseDAO()
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public List<Course> getAll()
        {
            string sql = "select * from university.course";
            List<Course> courses = conn.Query<Course>(@sql).ToList();
            return courses;
       }
   }
```

[image: Course Schema]

Expected:
Courses list have all courses from db with correct values.

Actual
Courses list has all courses from db with id and did as null and rest have values.

Comment: You have incorrect property names in your class. Change Id to course_id and DId to department_id or vice versa. By default dapper tries to apply values by name (using ignore case strategy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if issue was solved in question comments by [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4940991/maxim-goncharuk), I'd like to describe problem with few solution alternatives.

**Problem cause:**

Dapper executes mapping from sql query result to object **by name**. Sql query result field 'title' is automatically mapped to Course.Title (mapping is case-*insensitive*).

In your case there was two name-mismatches between  db columns vs. C# properties: (`course_id` != `Id` and `department_id` != `DId`), therefore Dapper was unable to map those fields.

**Solution 1, sql column aliases**

You can list table columns with possible columns aliases in sql query following way:

```
string sql = "select course_id Ad Id, title, credits, Is_elective, department_id as DId, sem from university.course";
```

Using explicit column names in sql, Dapper can execute automatic name-based mappings.

**Solution 2, Dapper custom mappings**

[Dapper Custom mapping](https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-columns-mapping-1cd45dfd51d6) is the feature to manually define, for each object, which column is mapped to which property.

Here is class which deal with the mappings (idea for this both-ways mapping borrowed from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938140/5789864)):

```
    public class ColumnMap
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public void Add(string t1, string t2)
        {
            mappings.Add(t1, t2);
        }

        public string this[string index]
        {
            get
            {
                // Check for a custom column map.
                if (forward.ContainsKey(index))
                    return forward[index];
                if (reverse.ContainsKey(index))
                    return reverse[index];

                // If no custom mapping exists, return the value passed in.
                return index;
            }
        }
    }
```

Setup the ColumnMap object and tell Dapper to use the mapping.

```
var columnMap = new ColumnMap();
columnMap.Add("Id", "course_id");
columnMap.Add("DId", "department_id");

SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof (Course), new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof (Course), (type, columnName) => type.GetProperty(columnMap[columnName])));
```

**Solution 3, dynamic type and LINQ**
You can execute field mapping using dynamic object as following:

```
string sql = "select * from university.course";
List<Course> courses = conn.Query<dynamic>(@sql)
   .Select(item => new Course()
   {
     Id = item.course_id,
     Title = item.title,
     Credits = item.credits,
     Is_Elective = item.Is_elective,
     DId = department_id,
     Sem = sem
   })
   .ToList();
```