# Get specific column from a dapper result set

Tags: c#, list, linq, dapper

I'm new using Dapper and I want a better way to fetch data from a certain column in a Dapper row. Data is being retrieved from a stored procedure that returns 1 or more rows with 5 columns but I only need to get 1 column data for this specific method. My code is actually working but I know there's a better way to write this and would love to apply it.

Here's the sample result from stored procedure:
{{DapperRow, prodid = 'b1', prodname = 'sample product', description = 'test only', qty = '1', remainingstock = '10'}}

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
     var products = new List<Product>();
            using (var db = DbConnection)
            {
                var data = //sp call here

                //code for improvement starts here
                foreach (var row in data)
                {
                    foreach (var col in row)
                    {
                        if (col.Key == "prodname")
                        {
                            var product = new Product
                            {
                                DisplayResult = col.Value
                            };
                            products.Add(product);
                            break; //skip the remaining columns
                        }
                    }
                }
                //to here
            }

        return products;
```

expected result would be:
products[0].DisplayResult = "sample product"

Answer (score 2):

Cast your row to dictionary and access by column name.

```
var data = (IDictionary<string,object>)row;
object value = data["prodname"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the recommended strong typed way mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497965/194717), you can also use Dapper with `dynamic` to access the columns on a DapperRow:

```
{{DapperRow, prodid = 'b1', prodname = 'sample product', description = 'test only', qty = '1', remainingstock = '10'}}
```

For example:

```
var row = conn.QueryFirst<dynamic>("SELECT prodid as ID, PRODNAME as Name FROM products").QTD;

var ID = row.ID;
var Name = row.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the most compelling feature of Dapper; it will map the Products for you

It's supposed to work like (super simplified:

```
class Product{
  int ID;
  string Name;
}
```

And if your column names in the db don't match then you alias them in the query:

```
using(con = ...){
  var prodList = con.Query<Product>("select prodid as ID, prodname as Name from products where prodid between @a and @b", new{ a = 1, b = 100});
}
```

That's it: dapper runs the query and generates you an ienumerable full of Products, without the "row by row, if column then ..."

As you're using an sp you have a problem in that you cannot alias your columns but you can either:

- use a technique to map your column names with your properties - [Manually map column names with class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902674/manually-map-column-names-with-class-properties)
- run the sp and accept an ienumerable of anonymous type with properties named as the sp outputted them (you're doing something like this currently) then use a LINQ select to create your products; it would look something like `con.Query("spname", ..params..).Select(e => new Product(){ ID = e.prodid, Name = e.prodname})`
- don't use the sp; select from the tables and alias the columns to match your properties (more like how dapper was intended to be used)