# Insert Enum Value to database - Data truncated for column 'CustomerGroup'

Tags: c#, database, enums, insert, blazor

I have problem with inserting record with enum to database using Blazor framework.

**My model looks like this: **

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } //primary, auto-increment
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string VATNum { get; set; }
        public CustomerGroup CustomerGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

**Enum**

```
public enum CustomerGroup
    {
        National,
        Foreign
    }
```

**Method with sql and db query call**

```
public Task InsertCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO Customer (CompanyName, VATNum, CustomerGroup) VALUES (@CompanyName, @VATNum, @CustomerGroup)";

            return _db.SaveData(sql, customer);
        }
```

**SaveData method**

```
public async Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName)))
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
            }
        }
```

I think the problem is that CustomerGroup is of type enum, not string, and blazor can't convert it.
When I hardcoded in sql variable, @CustomerGroup to 'National', everything works fine.

Best regards!

I tried to add [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] to enum declaration
Also tried to wrap field in model in [Column(TypeName= "nvarchar(10)")]

Nothing has helped

Comment: Are you using Dapper?

Comment: What is the datatype in your actual SQL table?  It should probably be an `int`.

Comment: @Charlieface yes, I'm using Dapper.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Database type is ENUM: 'National', 'Foreign'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dapper and Enums as Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264655/dapper-and-enums-as-strings)

Comment: If you're using dapper, you can just provide a new object: `new {ID = myobject.ID, CompanyName = myobject.CompanyName, VATNum = myobject.VatNum, CustomerGroup = myobject.CustomerGroup.ToString()}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. Unfortunately with my architecture I could not apply any of the solutions. I finally solved the problem by changing the field type in the database from enum to string. I do the validation of the enum correctness on the C# side.

For my use, the problem solved. If anyone would like to solve this problem "as it should be" I think the problem lies on the Dapper side.

Best Regards!